# References to theme object aren't working within the Theme UI theme

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emotion, theme-ui

#### TLDR

References in my Theme UI theme are being output as static values instead of resolving to the object property/value, meaning I get CSS output such as `font-family: heading;` where font-family should actually be mapping to `text.heading` and resolve to something like `font-family: Lato, sans-serif`.

The issue is the same whether I reference a theme value from within the theme or from a component (using something like `variant='text.h1'`). Similarly, color references such as `colors.primary` don't reolve either. It seems like I've done something fundamentally wrong in the configuration but I've uninstalled and re-followed the install steps and I'm getting them same outcome.

How do I make the theme references resolve properly?

#### Detail

I've installed Rebass and Theme UI using the getting started documentation for each of those libraries. Relevant bits of `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.2.1",
    "@theme-ui/mdx": "^0.15.4",
    "gatsby": "^5.3.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.3.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^5.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^6.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.3.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-theme-ui": "^0.15.4",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.3.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rebass": "^4.0.7",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "theme-ui": "^0.15.4",
  }
```

I've created my theme in basic form as per the docs:

```
const theme = {
  colors: {
    text: '#202020',
    background: '#f2f7f8',
    primary: '#095463',
    secondary: '#ff0000',
    black: '#202020',
    white: '#fefefe',
  },
  fonts: {
    body: 'Lato, sans-serif',
    heading: 'Lato, sans-serif',
  },
  fontSizes: [12, 14, 16, 20, 24, 32, 48, 64, 72],
  fontWeights: {
    body: 400,
    heading: 700,
    bold: 700
  },
  text: {
    heading: {
      color: 'secondary',
      fontFamily: 'heading',
      fontWeight: 'heading',
    },
    h3: {
      color: 'secondary',
      fontFamily: 'heading',
      fontWeight: 'heading',
    },
  },
  styles: {
    root: {
      fontFamily: 'body',
      lineHeight: 'body',
      fontWeight: 'body',
      color: 'primary'
    },
    h1: {
      variant: 'text.heading',
      fontSize: 5,
    },
    h3: {
      variant: 'text.h3',
      fontSize: 5,
    },
  },
}

export default theme
```

The root styles get applied correctly to the `html` element (e.g. font and colours as CSS variables such as `--theme-ui-colors-primary: #095463;` but none of the references within the theme work and neither do they when used on a component as a variant or as an `sx` prop.

If I inspect a heading, the CSS attributes show the static values (e.g. 'heading') rather than the references to the theme object:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After I had updated from `emotion-theming` to `@emotion/react` I got this problem, I found a problem caused here [ThemeProvider not working with Rebass](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2400#issuecomment-857727471).

The ThemeProvider from 'emotion-theming' and Rebass use the same ThemeContext from @emotion/core, but the ThemeProvider from '@emotion/react use @emotion/react's ThemeContext and Rebass still using @emotion/core's ThemeContext, [@iChenLei](https://github.com/iChenLei) suggests using emotion-theming or push Rebass library author to support @emotion/react(But it's looks like impossible cause Rebass is not a active project currently).